# How do I display html files with rocket.rs

Tags: web, rust, rocket

I am new to rust and I am trying to build a simple webpage with HTML.

This is my code:

```
use rocket::*;
use rocket::response::content::Html;

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> content::Html<&'static str> {
    content::Html(r#"
        <title>GCD Calculator</title>
        <form action="/gcd" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="n" />
            <input type="text" name="n" />
            <button type="submit">Compute GCD</button>
        </form>
    "#)
}

#[launch]
fn rocket()->_{
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![index])
}
```

But it returns the error:

```
   Compiling hello-rocket v0.1.0 (/home/garuda/dev/Rust/Rocket/hello-rocket)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `rocket::response::content::Html`
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use rocket::response::content::Html;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `Html` in `response::content`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `content`
 --> src/main.rs:5:15
  |
5 | fn index() -> content::Html<&'static str> {
  |               ^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `content`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `content`
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     content::Html(r#"
  |     ^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `content`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0432, E0433.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `hello-rocket` due to 3 previous errors
```

I know for sure that this module exists because https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/response/content/struct.Html.html

Comment: What's in your Cargo.toml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the (preview) Rocket 0.5.0-rc.2, the struct `Html` was renamed to [`RawHtml`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/response/content/struct.RawHtml.html). Replace `Html` with `RawHtml` and it'll work.

See also [the changelog](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/v0.5-rc/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes):

> - Content-Type [`content`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/response/content/index.html) responder type names are now prefixed with `Raw`.

Comment: Thanks it works, but how do i provide a link to the html file which it should display?

Comment: @GauravChandrashekar I don't understand. AFAIK the only change is the rename, everything that worked will continue to work.

Comment: I mean, if I have a file "test.html" how do I display that with rocket

Comment: @GauravChandrashekar This is another question. You can ask a new SO question for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72796739/how-do-i-displat-a-html-webpage-by-giving-the-link-with-rocket-rs this is the question

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the full path name to refer to that module, ie.

```rust
#[get("/")]
fn index() -> rocket::response::content::Html<&'static str> {
  rocket::response::content::Html(...)
}
```

Or add that specific module to the current namespace, with

```rust
use rocket::response::content;
```

In your code, you were only adding everything in the rocket module in your namespace  with `use rocket::*`, and the `Html` struct with `use::rocket::response::content::Html`, so as is you could also use `Html` directly:

```rust
fn index() -> Html<&'static str> {
  Html(...)
}
```

Comment: I tried all of them, It still returns the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of rocket?

Comment: [dependencies]
rocket = "0.5.0-rc.2"

my cargo.toml

Comment: This particular version doesn't seem to be documented on `docs.rs`. If you try downgrading to `0.5.0-rc.1`, does it work?

Comment: No it does not work