# How do I display a html webpage by giving the link with rocket.rs

Tags: web, rust, rocket

I am able to make a html webpage but with the html code in my .rs file. How do I separate it giving a link to the file to be displayed to rocket.rs?

My code:

```
use rocket::*;
use rocket::response::content::RawHtml;

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> RawHtml<&'static str> {
    RawHtml(r#"<h1>Hello world</h1>")
}

#[launch]
fn rocket()->_{
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![index])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the HTML document compiled in to your program so that it has no dependencies on external files, you can use the standard [`include_str!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) macro:

```
RawHtml(include_str!("index.html"))
```

This will look for `index.html` in the same directory as the `.rs` file the macro appears in during compilation, and insert the contents as a static string literal.

Alternatively, if you want the program to look for a file on disk at runtime, you can use Rocket's [`NamedFile`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/fs/struct.NamedFile.html) responder.